# Axie Infinity: query axie id from transaction information?

Tags: python, nft, moralis

Does anyone know how to get the transaction axie id from query?
I currently use Moralis to get the transaction hash and block number but I am not able to access which axie this transaction is taking on. Am I able to get this kind of information from a query or those transaction details are private keys and not for public access?